# Join 2 dataframes, while keeping exact left table

Tags: r, join, merge, left-join, inner-join

I want to join two tables (timeseries) while keeping every left entry (and NOT adding ones from the right) and adding things from the right only when they exist left and right. 
Kind of a left inner join (which probably does not exist).

For example I wanna join A with B and want to get AB:

```
   A= 
    1 
    2
    3
    4 

   B= 
    1 X
    2 Y
    2 Z
    4 Z
    5 ZZ

   AB= 
    1 X
    2 NaN
    3 NaN
    4 Z
```

2 and 3 are NaN because 2 exists multiple times and 3 does not exist on the right side

Thank you for the help

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Furthermore, you could start reading this Q&A: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Hey, I read all of the join and merge Q&As  and couldnt find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with cleanup and merge (left join) (probably far less efficient than @Pierre answer):

```
A <- structure(list(id = 1:4), .Names = "id", row.names = c(NA, -4L ), class = "data.frame")
B <- structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "2", "4", "5"), val = c("X", "Y", "Z", "Z", "ZZ")), .Names = c("id", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

# Cleanup duplicated id in B (could be used in the merge to avoid creating a new object, done here for ease of reading)
NB <- B[!B$id %in% B$id[duplicated(B$id)],]

# left merge of A and B on id
merge(A,NB,all.x=TRUE,by="id")
```

Gives:

```
  id  val
1  1    X
2  2 <NA>
3  3 <NA>
4  4    Z
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my question.
it can happen, that B is longer then A, then I think we cant use ur answer.

Comment: @Squeezie you're thinking wrong. with edited data it still gives 4 rows (I.e: the same number of rows than A)

Comment: It perfectly did the job it should. Thank you!

Comment: @Squeezie glad it helped, but you should really try pierre's answer. I'm pretty sure it will be quicker and more efficient

Comment: Actually yours did the work in under 1 second for a ~300.000 length vector, while pierres took over 1 minute (if I did it right).

Answer (score 3):

You mention 'time-series' data in your question. That type of data can come in a general table format or a specific R `ts` object. The `ts` class is a special type of vector or matrix given special properties to assist in time-series analysis. We will assume for this approach that you have the latter case, an object of `class(A) [1] "data.frame"`.

This is less a merge than a conditional match. We can test if there is one and only one match of the `A` values in `B`:

```
indx <- sapply(A$col1, function(x) sum(B$col1 %in% x) == 1L)
data.frame(v1=A$col1, v2=ifelse(indx, B$col2, NaN), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#   v1  v2
# 1  1   X
# 2  2 NaN
# 3  3 NaN
# 4  4   Z
```

Note: Be sure to not fall into the `factor` trap. R automatically codes character values into class `factor` not into class `character` as you might expect at first. To avoid this issue use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`,

```
#Data
A <- data.frame(col1=1:4L)
B <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,2,4), col2=c("X", "Y", "Z", "Z"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```